# Exchange – two accounts on one Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-office-2010

I’ve got a problem with Outlook 2010 and Office 365 Exchange Online.

I try to configure two account on one Outlook. First I add my primary account (lets says first@ms.com) and then I add second account (second@ms.com). 
Other person from my company do the same thing – and we’ve got a problem – sometimes we  cannot connect to our secondary account (I have added secondary account second@ms.com any college to the same thing). When we try to send something from this second account the email message was put in the “Send Items” folder but don’t send.

We try to install SP1 for Office 2010 but with no result:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeappcompat/thread/4480fe13-df71-4d25-9600-2dac368c752c/

We try “Configure Send As permissions” – this work but I need to keep the send email on the second@ms.com account – with this issue keep send email in “Send Items” in my primary (frist@ms.com) account.

Have you got any solution?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

I never managed to successfully work with Office 365 + any other Exchange account. I always had some kind of glitches. So the only solution I found is to create two separate Outlook profiles and add each account to separate profile. After that I set Outlook to ask for profile each time I run it.

Not too comfortable, but works.